# Create react blink color component

Tags: reactjs, colors, blink

Can anybody show me how to make color blink (green/red) component like this site does https://www.exchangecompare.com/.

Any solution suggest would be much appreciated ?

Answer (score 6):

Since it is a quite simple animation, I would rather use simple CSS classes and transition effects to achieve that goal.

Imagine, you have the trigger "highlight". If the component gets trigger highlight, it should do the blinking.
What you can do, is simply add that as a class "highlight" to that element if it should blink (based on the trigger). Once the class got added, you do the animation transition from the base color to the highlighting color. Then, after 2s (or so) you remove the class again and the component should fade back to the base color.

So far so good.

The CSS for that would look somewhat like that:

```
.element {
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
  color: black;
  padding: 20px;
}

.highlight {
  color: #ff0000;
}
```

(.element is the base element that keeps the transition logic, .highlight has just included whatever should change)

Some basic react:

```
const BlinkingComponent = ({ highlighting }) => (
  <div className={`element${highlighting ? " highlight" : ""}`}>Watch Me</div>
);

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    highlight: false
  };

  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({ highlight: true });
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ highlight: false });
    }, 2000);
  };

  render() {
    const { highlight } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <button onClick={() => this.handleClick()}>Click me</button>
        <BlinkingComponent highlighting={highlight} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

See it working: https://codesandbox.io/s/61502wxlw3

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to know more specific details about how the component should constructed with state and props. But this is definitely useful!

Comment: Well, for my understanding you did not really ask for that. You asked for "How can I make a component blink?" I updated my answer to meet the expectation of showing it in a separate component. For sure, if you want to highlight the component in different colors depending on the previous value, you need to compare the previous value with the new one and then set the highlighting according to your result like you did it in your answer. But this is at least from what I saw not really in the scope of your original question. :)

Comment: Yes thank you for comment, I really use your suggested styles though! :)

Comment: I had to add a space before the '$' to make this work. Works great, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering how to determine the previous value once component change, and I ended up using `componentDidUpdate` to access previous value before rendering, I use Typescript:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import './ChangeColor.css';

interface IChangeColorProps {
  value: number;
}

interface IChangeColorState {
  stateClass: string;
}

export class ChangeColor extends React.Component<IChangeColorProps, IChangeColorState> {
  private timeout: NodeJS.Timeout;

  public componentDidUpdate(prevProps: IChangeColorProps) {
    if (prevProps.value < this.props.value) {
      this.setState({ stateClass: ' highlight-up' });
    } else if (prevProps.value > this.props.value) {
      this.setState({ stateClass: ' highlight-down' });
    } else {
      return;
    }

    clearTimeout(this.timeout);
    this.timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ stateClass: '' });
    }, 1200);
  }

  public render(): JSX.Element {
    const stateClass = this.state ? this.state.stateClass : '';

    return <span className={`element${stateClass}`}>
      {this.props.value}
    </span>;
  }
}
```

Usage

```
<ChangeColor value={myVal} />
```